# Why did this SQL Server view stop working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather long view thahas been working for years.  After upgrading the server to SQL server 2014.  I started getting a bind error: dboSubjects.Race" could not be bound.

The dboSubjects.Race is used like this in the view:

```
dbo.SUBJECTS.Race, dbo.SUBJECTS.Sex, dboSubjects.Race + dbo.SUBJECTS.Sex AS RaceSex,
```

If I remove the

```
dboSubjects.Race + dbo.SUBJECTS.Sex AS RaceSex
```

The view then functions.  Can anyone explain how I can fix this problem and explain why it stopped working.  I can only quess that the upgrade had something to do with it.

Thanks for your help
Perry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dboSubjects.Race + dbo.SUBJECTS.Sex AS RaceSex
```

You are missing a dot in the first part - should probably be `dbo.Subjects.Race`

Comment: Duh I have been looking at that line of code for over an hour and just did not see that.  Thanks for you help